routing domain name to aws load balancer connected to aws fargate
I created an application and loaded it into a docker container and deployed it on AWS Fargate , now I want to change the DNS of the load balancer to a domain I have on godaddy, I have tried the regular way but It seems not to work.
Also, the domain name was also transferred to namecheap. (I guess i will have to unsubscribe from this and use just go daddy).
Below is what I have done so far...the domain name still route to the current website, I create a new app and want to route the domain name to the app on AWS Fargate
My load balancer

my Route53

My go daddy account

so based on the comment below, I went and created a Network load balancer that routes traffic to the application load balancer, now i want to add a domain name, how do i go about it?

if you recently changed the dns then it will take sometime for your domain to propage with your new dns settings

Godaddy does not support alias for AWS resources, you might have to move Nameserver to Route53. If you have to keep the NS there then you have to use NLB and forward traffic to ALB. For details see:
Application Load Balancer-type Target Group for Network Load Balancer
Update:
Reason for using NLB in front of ALB is that NLB provides static IPs per AZ. Those IPs can be used as a value of A record in you respective DNS. In case of godaddy this is how you can Edit an A record.

I have now created the Network load balancer that routes traffic to the Application load balancer…how then do I now add the godaddy domain name to the NLB?

When setting up the route53 domain, when I unselect the alias, it asks me to input a value and some other parameters, can you help, I’ll share an image of what I was asked.

I used the IP address of the NLB to create the route 53 record without using alias...i want to wait 24hr and see...that should work right?

@OsemuAimiosior NLB provides static IPs for each AZ. You'll need to add/update A records in godaddy to point to those IPs. I've also update the answer.

so this mean i would not need to modify the namservers on my godaddy account, right? just the DNS record with all the AZ IP of my NLB right?

@OsemuAimiosior correct, if you are going NLB route.
